# Register LongClick listener on a Seekbar

Tags: android

In android, is it possible for me to register a long click listener on a seekbar?

I have done this:

```
mySeekBar.setLongClickable(true);
mySeekBar.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
   public boolean onLongClick (View v) {
    Log.d("TEST", "Get a long click event!!!!!!!!!!!!");
 }
});
```

But I don't see my debug print statement at all. Any idea about how can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: `mySeekBar.setLongClickable(true)` is not necessary, the listener setter will switch the control to long-clickable before it attaches the listener, at least in v1.5 and later. Does your second line really have a question mark in it?

Comment: No. I don't have a '?' in my actual code. But it still does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT this is not possible to do with the `OnLongClickListener`. The documentation doesn't say it **won't** work, but I've never seen any example of this (and I never got it to work myself either).

A possible workaround (depending on what you want to achieve) could be to use the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` handling the long click through `onStartTrackingTouch` / `onStopTrackingTouch` callbacks.

Comment: I've traced the inheritance from View, too, and can find no override that should prevent this. I have been unable to find a working example, either, though, nor have I been able to get longClick to fire on a SeekBar in practice. Confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

While not mentioned in the documentation, I've experimentally determined that both click and long-click listeners are unsupported on SeekBars.  They are supported in ProgressBars.

Digging through the source code shows why: `SeekBar.onTouchEvent()` does not call `super.onTouchEvent()`.  It is in `View.onTouchEvent()` that `performClick()` and `performLongClick()` are called, as appropriate.  So the only way to handle long-clicks on a `SeekBar` is to manually detect them.

My own thinking is that having a long-click handler for a `SeekBar` doesn't actually make sense.  If the user is dragging the "thumb" for longer than the long-click threshold/delay, suddenly you have a long-press that probably was not meant as one. You can cancel and reset the delay every time the thumb is moved, requiring a long-press to be several seconds in exactly one position. But it's rare to be perfectly still; it's in fact difficult to hold the thumb yet not move it for several seconds. So you could then have a minimum change in thumb position that resets the delay. That's what I would do if I had to, but I must say it's a very strange user experience.  There are many places in Android where a user expects a long-press to be significant, but a `SeekBar` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could sub-class SeekBar and implement your own onLongClick listener. This is not for the faint of heart, but [Terry Long](http://www.cnblogs.com/TerryBlog/archive/2010/08/31/1813481.html) seems to have done it in a round-about way. (At least I *think* he has, my Mandarin is pretty rusty.) He lays out four steps:

- Sub-class SeekBar, overriding setOnLongClickListener to kill it
- Create a thread that terminates after the desired "long click" time
- Create a "long click" event that gets fired when the thread terminates
- Override the SeekBar OnSeekBarChangeListener event handler to handle the event

I haven't tried his code, but the basic idea looks sound. I would have thought he would have tried to do this in AbsSeekBar to avoid overriding SeekBar's OnSeekBarChangeListener, but he doesn't say why he didn't do it that way (again, AFAICT).

Sounds like overkill to me, though. ProgressBar *does* support long clicks; could you use that somehow?