# android seekbar handle - long key press

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to implement event trigger on long keypress on android seekbar thumb handle.

Does anyone knows if it's possible to identify long keypress on seek bar handle (thumb picture)?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any method to support long-press event particularly on the thumb drawable. However you may achieve this with some custom logic as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641779/register-longclick-listener-on-a-seekbar) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried, but it should work.

```
SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(Activity.this);
        seek.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```